# Is it feasible to hike Zion and Bryce in Utah in mid-May?

Tags: hiking, united-states, trails

Is it feasible to hike trails to at least some overlooks around [Zion National Park](https://www.nps.gov/zion/learn/news/climbingclosures_2_28_17.htm) and [Bryce Canyon](https://www.nps.gov/brca/index.htm) in Utah in mid-May? If yes, do we need a 4x4, or will a sedan do?

We are only interested in day hikes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can definitely hike Zion/Bryce in May. In fact it is a good time of the year for hiking in that area. A sedan will do just fine for most trailheads.

Comment: So we do need an SUV to access some trailheads, right? Do rental cars come with gear to brush off snow and scrape off ice? Could we need that?

Comment: I would not assume that ice scrapers would be included -- the good old' credit card somewhat works if you are out of luck. I would not expect  snow/ice at that time of the year. I don't know of any trail head in Bryce/Zion that a SUV would be required.

Comment: Thanks - once we woke up and saw a quarter inch layer of ice on a rental car. Had to wait until the car warmed up and the ice started to melt away.

Comment: Note that in Zion, the popular trailheads are only accessible by shuttle bus.

Answer (score 5):

Zion has only one unpaved road you're likely to want to drive on: a one-mile stretch of the Lava Point road.  That road is marked on the map as "impassible when wet", which I suspect means an SUV won't do any better than a sedan in bad weather; it's not marked as high-clearance, so a sedan will do just fine in good weather.

There are no unpaved roads in Bryce; the roads are either open to everything or closed to all traffic depending on the conditions.